# Prevent Angular from polluting global namespace

Tags: angular, typescript

This question is specific to the new Angular, previously known as Angular 2. This is not about AngularJS, previously known as Angular 1.

When I bootstrap an Angular application, it likes to put a number of functions/objects at the global namespace. window.ng, window.getAllAngularRootElements etc.

Is there a way to easily ask Angular, to not pollute the global namespace, and instead allowing the developer to specify a namespace in which to keep everything in? Examples using Typescript would be best! Thanks!